# List Authors, but Exclude Admin in Wordpress child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am trying to list authors on a page, but exclude the admin (myself). I am using a child theme of squirrel and this is my code so far:

```
<?php
    $authors = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM '.$wpdb->posts);
    if($authors):
    foreach($authors as $author):
    ?>
    <div class='author' id='author-<?php the_author_meta('user_login', $author->post_author); ?>'>
    <h3><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/author/<?php the_author_meta('user_login', $author->post_author); ?>"><?php the_author_meta('display_name', $author->post_author); ?></a></h3>

        <?php if(get_the_author_meta('description', $author->post_author)): ?>
        <div class='description'>
            <?php echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('user_email', $author->post_author), 80); ?>
            <p><?php the_author_meta('description', $author->post_author); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        $recentPost = new WP_Query('author='.$author->post_author.'&showposts=1');
        while($recentPost->have_posts()): $recentPost->the_post();
        ?>
        <h4>Recent Article: <a href='<?php the_title();?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

I tried using the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541317/wordpress-list-authors-and-exclude-admin) discussion, but I don't think I am doing it right because when I add this line of code:

```
if(get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author->post_author) != 'admin'):
```

under:

```
foreach ($authors as $author):
```

it just breaks the entire site (the screen is white). This is all new to me, so can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does your web server software's error log report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *white screen* you are experiencing is a fatal PHP error. You are not seeing what the error is, for security reasons.

However, during development, you want this feature off. Just edit `wp-config.php` and set `WP_DEBUG` to `true`.

As for your question, you might want something like:

```
if($author->post_author == 1) continue;
```

...as the first line inside the `foreach`. The id 1 should be your userid because the first user created in WP has 1, and the keyword `continue` jumps to the end of the foreach, thus skipping your user.

If you prefer doing this by username, use this:

```
if(get_the_author_meta('user_login', $author->post_author) == 'admin') continue;
```